# Does military power accumulate in Race for the Galaxy

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

I have one card placed down with a plus one to my military on phase three. I have already placed down a card in a previous settle phase that cost one military.

If another settle phase comes along can I play a hostile card that costs 1 military?

I would then have placed two cards down based on that +1 military.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Military power is not "used up" when you settle a world. All that matters is that each time you are settling a military world, you have enough military power to meet the requirement. So yes, even if you only have 1 military power, you can settle multiple worlds that each have a requirement of 1.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use the same military power bonus over and over again.

At any time, you can count up your total military power from what's in your tableau. For example, if you have Space Marines (+2) and Drop Ships (+3), your total military is 5. That means that you can conquer any military world with defense at most 5. It doesn't matter when you played each development, or what military worlds you may have played in the past; your current military power is still 5.

So I wouldn't think of it as military worlds *costing* military to settle. You just compare your military power to their defense, and see if you have enough. Using your military power doesn't expend it.

Comment: To expand on this point just a bit, there is also one card that grants a temporary military bonus.  "_New Military Tactics may be discarded from a player’s tableau for +3 Military until the end of that settle phase._"  This kinda implies that other military sources are static (or at least considered "renewable").

Comment: @ryanyuyu True, though I'd emphasize that that's still different from the idea of "using up" military. You get that amount of military until the end of the phase, not just until you use it. (So for example, with Improved Logistics, which lets you settle/conquer twice within the phase, New Military Tactics can be used to grant +3 military to conquer two worlds.)

Comment: Note also that with expansion cards such as Imperium Supply Convoy it is explicitly the case that after using up part of your military (say, 3/5) to conquer a world, you may only use the *remainder* (2/5) to conquer another. However this doesn't apply to the base game and is specific to this particular card; but just to point out that such a case may indeed exist. Example: https://cf.geekdo-images.com/original/img/e815a8jiYVNc8Jf3SHN8855mC0s=/0x0/pic1839380.jpg